# mvn- look for wrong url in maven repositories

Tags: maven

When I run mvn package to compile a maven project it downloads the jar file from
wrong URLs. It adds org/dnosproject/ to the URL which is wrong.

Downloading: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.dnos-project/dnos-lib-all/org/dnosproject/onos-port-protobuf/1.1.5/onos-port-protobuf-1.1.5.jar

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dnos-lib-all</id>
            <name>dnos-lib</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.dnos-project/dnos-lib-all</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.dnos-project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dnos-lib-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You may want to show the relevant parts of your POM (`pom.xml`). Specifically, what `<dependency/>` did you add for this artifact, and did you make any specific `repository` settings in the POM (or your `settings.xml`)?

Comment: Yes. I added them. Please take a look.

Comment: I also don't have settings.xml. Do I need to have one?

Comment: Never mind. I think I figured that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website mvnrepository.com is a kind of search engine across multiple real Maven repositories. If you look at [the link you mentioned in your `<repository/>` configuration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.dnos-project/dnos-lib-all), you'll notice they list that dependency as available in "Central", in fact [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=dnos-lib-all). "Central" is configured by default, so you don't need a `<repository/>` configuration for this dependency. Instead, you just need the correct `<dependency/>` entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.dnos-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>dnos-lib-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You already had this in the snippet you posted, so just removing the `<repository/>` configuration should do the trick.